# why can I require gems which are outside from $LOAD_PATH

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I installed a gem `coffee-cup` in my rvm gem set,`ruby-2.1.1@test` whose path is `/Users/dingxijin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@test/gems/coffee-cup-0.0.4`.

Then I open irb,just like this:

```
2.1.1 :001 > puts $:
/Users/dingxijin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0
/Users/dingxijin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0
/Users/dingxijin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/Users/dingxijin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0
/Users/dingxijin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0
/Users/dingxijin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/Users/dingxijin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0
/Users/dingxijin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0
 => nil
2.1.1 :002 > require "coffee-cup"
NameError: uninitialized constant CoffeeCup::Rails
    from /Users/dingxijin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@test/gems/coffee-cup-0.0.4/lib/coffee-cup/engine.rb:2:in `<module:CoffeeCup>' ..........
```

**Does ruby search gems from the $LOAD_PATH directories?
why can I require `coffee-cup`,it's obviously that $LOAD_PATH doesn't have its directory?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original, “normal” behaviour of `require` is how you have described it: the `LOAD_PATH` is searched for the requested file and if it’s not found a `LOAD_ERROR` is raised. Rubygems modifies this behaviour by [replacing the `Kernel#require` method](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_2/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb#L24-L38). The comment to the new `require` method explains what happens:

> When RubyGems is required, Kernel#require is replaced with our own which
>   is capable of loading gems on demand.
>
> When you call `require 'x'`, this is what happens:
>
> - If the file can be loaded from the existing Ruby loadpath, it
>     is.
> - Otherwise, installed gems are searched for a file that matches.
>     If it's found in gem 'y', that gem is activated (added to the
>     loadpath).
>
> The normal `require` functionality of returning false if
>   that file has already been loaded is preserved.

With Rubygems included in Ruby by default, this new behaviour is now the norm.

In your example if you look at the load path again after you have required a file from a gem you should see the gems’ path has been added.

Comment: Thank you very much.I have googled much and no one else talking about this.I think ruby need to make efforts to improve their documentation.